# "This bed can _____ a 500 kg load without bending", which word is correct?

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I have a sentence:

> This bed can ____ a 500 kg load without bending

Which word should I use to fill the blank? I have thought of 2 words: **possess** and **have** but which one is correct?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Neither word fits.  "Hold" or "support" might be appropriate.  "Possess means to own, and the closest relevant definition of "have" would be a meaning something like "contain as part of it's structure".

Comment: You can use the verbs bear, hold or sustain instead of possess and have.

Answer (score 1):

*Possess* doesn't seem right because it sounds too much like the bed owns the weight, or that the weight is a feature of the bed. *Have* also sounds like ownership to me here, so I don't think it works very well.

If we rephrase it as

> This bed can **have** a 500 kg  load **on it** without bending

then it is very clear that the weight is applied to the bed and that it is a notable feat.

Returning to the original structure, I think some better options are *hold, carry,* and *support*.

> - [hold](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hold)
>     4 c:  to bear the pressure of :  support • can the roof hold all of that weight
> - [carry](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/carry)
>     11 :  to sustain the weight or burden of • Pillars carry an arch. • is carrying a full course load
> - [support](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/support)
>     4 a :  to hold up or serve as a foundation or prop for

I think they're all equally good.

Answer (score 0):

I would offer slightly different suggestions based on what type of bed is being referred to. These suggestions can be used interchangeably for both types of bed, so its not a hard distinction.

If the 'bed' in question is a **bed used for sleeping**, then I would offer the following (among many) options:

> This bed can **carry** a 500 kg load without bending.
>
> This bed can **support** a 500 kg load without bending.
>
> This bed can **hold** a 500 kg load without bending.
>
> This bed can **take** a 500 kg load without bending.

On the other hand, if the 'bed' in question is an **industrial bed** (e.g. the load bed of a vehicle), then I'd be swayed towards phrasing it like:

> This bed can **withstand** a 500 kg load without bending.
>
> This bed can **support** a 500 kg load without bending.

**Nuances in Meaning**

As mentioned at the start of the answer, these suggestions are not exclusionary based on the type of bed, but can be used interchangeably.

- In the first instance (bed to sleep on) the word '*carry*' has a
  nicer supportive connotation, whereas using '*withstand*' might give
  the impression that the users of the bed are heavy, and that the bed
  is just about coping with such a weight.
- In the second instance (load bed), the word '*withstand*' gives the
  impression that it is a mechanical limit or capacity targeted at
  professional users.

These are small nuances between different words that you might wish to pay attention to based on the audience of the sentence (e.g. if this is a marketing statement, then go for a word that is least likely to be misinterpreted or cause offence; if this is a technical document, then pick the word that is most accurate or relevant).

Answer (score 0):

Support or withstand seems to be the more appropriate answer and not possess or have. They are described well as above.

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Please [edit] to include an explanation of why this is correct; answers without explanation aren't particularly helpful. See the [Submitting Answers that merely answer the question](//meta.ell.stackexchange.com/q/1117) discussion on meta. Also, when I view this page there is nothing "above" your answer - answers can change order, be edited, or be deleted, so your answer should stand on its own.